# Is there a difference between Git commit then checkout and checkout then commit?

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose I am on a branch `develop` with changed files:

Is there any difference (Git wise) if I do:

```
$ git add *somefiles*
$ git commit
$ git checkout -b fix/new_branch
$ git push origin fix/new_branch
```

Instead of:

```
$ git checkout -b fix/new_branch
$ git add *somefiles*
$ git commit
$ git push origin fix/new_branch
```

Comment: Yes. In the first case, the commit is reachable ("part of") `new_branch` *and*  the branch that was checked out before. In the second case, the commit is only reachable via `new_branch`. When you continue to work on the branch that was checked out before, you will work on top of the commit in case one, and not have the commit in your history in case two.

Comment: The only difference is the new commit is **committed for both current branch and fix/new_branch branches** or **only committed for fix/new_branch**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the first case your changes (which you add by `git add *somefiles*`) will be there in both new and original branch while in later changes will just be in new branch.

So if you want your changes to go to remote of new branch, you should chose the second option.

Answer (score 0):

In either case, the contents of `fix/new_branch` is the same, but in your second example, `develop` will not contain the recent changes until merged back.

Answer (score 0):

## Git commit then checkout work like below

yes there is difference is that if we are using first commit at that time it will commit in local repository only. after that we will take update at that time git will check when if server and local committed branch having same file changes at that time it will ask for merger

`$ git add *somefiles*
$ git commit
$ git checkout -b fix/new_branch
$ git push origin fix/new_branch`

## checkout then commit

it will not check if merge is available or not in local respository. it will force to commit your task

always practice first one it is best